# Screen flashing black

Tags: ubuntu, hardware-failure, dell-vostro

my screen is suffering some black flashes, as fast as the blink of an eye. It's not periodical, like twice in a half and hour period but it happens constantly. What system logs can help me determine if it's a hardware or software problem? And if you might, please help me troubleshoot it. My setup is a dell vostro 5470 with ubuntu 14.04.

Already tried this: https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2015/01/08/fixing-nvidia-flickering-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-gnome/ but didn't solved it.

Comment: "This flickering didn’t affect the whole screen, rather it seemed to be something to do with window repainting, ..." <- if that is not what you see, I'd seriously suspect hardware. Hardware running hot might be the basic root cause.

Comment: The link you shared to compiz tool actually worked for me :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

We have seen this issue on Dell OptiPlex systems running Win 7, NVIDIA cards and dual 24" monitors. Logs didn't show anything. Diagnostics all passed. After old fashioned troubleshooting by replacing the video card, the monitors (Dell, AOC & Samsung), the connection type to the monitor and changes in drivers and updates to the system firmware. It was a power and switching issue. It was permanently fixed by newer systems with more internal power - moving from Core 2 Quad systems to I7 & Xeon systems. We still have a few of the older systems and users report the flashes from time to time.